# Could the cosmological constant $\Lambda$ decay with time and still have $w=-1$?

Tags: cosmology, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

One of the larger puzzles (coincidences) of cosmology is that the cosmological constant $\Lambda$ has roughly the value given by the radius of the present universe.

At the same time, cosmological data states that dark energy obeys $w=-1$ with a high precision of only a few percent. This is usually interpreted as meaning that dark energy / the cosmological constant is really *constant* in time.

Could it be that $\Lambda$ decays with time (and is always given by the radius of the universe, thus avoiding the coincidence issue) and that $w=-1$ holds nevertheless?

For example, could it be that dark energy is constantly replenished somehow, so that this is not a contradiction?

Comment: What do you mean by "constantly replenished somehow"

Comment: Well, dark energy could continuously arise from the horizon.

Comment: If it decay wouldnt it mean its density changes ? I mean I did not understand the point of replenishing

Comment: Could Lambda always be given by the cosmological radius (within a factor of order one), and w still follow w = –1 ? That is the question. The rest is unimportant.